# Why is ajax form submitting twice on checkbox change?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am experiencing a strange issue where an ajax form is submitting twice.

```
# view  
<%= simple_form_for user, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :approved,
    as: :boolean,
    input_html: { class: 'submit-on-select' } %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

# js
$("input:checkbox.submit-on-select").each ->
  $(this).closest('form').find('input[type="submit"]').each ->
    $(this).addClass('hidden')
  $("input:checkbox.submit-on-select").on 'change', ->
    $form = $(this).closest('form')
    $form.submit()
```

Clicking the checkbox should submit the form, yet the logs are showing a double submit with the `approved` changing for each submit

```
Started PATCH "/en/users/23" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-01-13 07:25:40 +0700
Processing by UsersController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"approved"=>"0"}, "locale"=>"en", "id"=>"23"}
Started PATCH "/en/users/23" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-01-13 07:25:40 +0700
Processing by UsersController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"approved"=>"1"}, "locale"=>"en", "id"=>"23"}
```

I have tried changing the JS as below, but the double post continues:

```
...
$form.unbind('submit').submit()
```

I am trying to track down what is causing the double post. In Chrome developer panel, the network tab shows two post events, but they both have exactly the same trace in the initiator column.

What could be causing this double post, and what is a sensible approach to debug this?

Comment: did you tried disabling Turbolinks ?

Comment: thanks @Milind I don't think turbolinks is enabled in this app. It is not in the application.js manifest or gemfile

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't need to use `.each` with `.addClass()`, just call it directly on the selection and it will operate on everything.

Comment: why are you submitting form using js & remote: true? may be thats why its invoking twice?

Comment: @uDaY thanks I thought this might be the case. But I removed remote and it still submits twice.

Comment: @uDaY also `$form.submit()` simply submits the form using whichever protocol is defined. If an ajax submit is needed, I belive `remote=true` is still needed even when submitting with JS. The alternative is to intercept the submit action with JS and write a new post method. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Debugging suggestion: add a `console.log('changed');` in the `.on 'change', ->` function and check browser console if it's being triggered twice.

Comment: thanks @mrlew, it is indeed being triggered twice

Comment: after much digging, I've finally traced this back to Switchery which is enabled on this checkbox. http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/ After disabling Switchery the form is posted only once. Any suggestions why Swicthery should cause this double post?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `return false` after or under `$form.submit()` or use `preventDefault()`

Comment: Thanks @bxorcloud. After adding these the form still submits twice.  
after much digging, I've finally traced this back to Switchery which is enabled on this checkbox. abpetkov.github.io/switchery After disabling Switchery the form is posted only once. Any idea why Swicthery should cause this double post?

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone else experiencing this issue, I eventually traced the problem back to Swicthery which is enabled on these checkboxes.

Specifically, this page helped solve the problem.

https://github.com/abpetkov/switchery/issues/50

Simpleform was wrapping the checkbox in a label tag

```
<label><input type="checkbox"></label>
```

which for some reason causes this double posting.

As I wanted to keep simpleform adding `boolean_style: :inline` removed the label tags and all is now working correctly.